# ShareKit programmatically click "publish"

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios, voice-recognition, sharekit

**EDIT:** It should be noted that I stated in my original question that I was able to get this working for Twitter (I used the referenced question/answer to get that working) . . . I just needed the answer for how to do it with Facebook. I haven't found an equivalent way to do this with Facebook.

I'm using ShareKit to allow my users to share data from my App with Facebook and Twitter.

I'm having a particular issue with Facebook sharing.

My App is almost completely voice controlled, so upon a voice command I call:

```
// Create the item to share (in this example, a url)
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:@"http://someurl.com" title:@"some title"];

// Share the item
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

This works fine, except the user is presented with a dialog (I think a UIWebView) that allows them to edit the post and either cancel or publish.

Since the App is voice controlled, I want to skip this step, basically programmatically click "publish" for them (call the publish method programmatically).  I don't mind if that dialog appears briefly and then goes away (this is how I handle Twitter, I was able to figure out how to do this with Twitter).  I'm having no luck finding this publish method though - I assume this is because it is a server side call handled by FBConnect.

Any ideas on a) what code to use to do this, and b) where to put that code)?

Many thanks in advance.

Ben

Comment: Any ideas?  This one is really driving me crazy.  I must confess I'm fairly ignorant with UIWebViews.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810146/is-it-possible-to-bypass-the-tweet-dialog-and-post-directly-to-twitter should answer your question.

Comment: unfortunately that only works for Twitter - need to figure out how to do it with Facebook

Comment: Do **NOT** edit out the duplicate header.  If you do not believe it is a duplicate, go about it in other ways.  Defacing content like this may result in further moderator action.

Comment: My bad, I was not aware of the protocol. Thanks to you (or whoever made the change) for removing the duplicate tag from the post.