# Is it possible to bypass the share dialog and post directly to Facebook? in share kit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

i Successfully  bypass the Twite dialog and post directly to Twitter In **ShareKit** using following Code

```
 SHKTwitter *twitter = [SHKTwitter new];
[twitter authorize];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem new];
[item setCustomValue:@"i am tweeting" forKey:@"status"];
twitter.item = item;
[twitter send];
item.shareType = SHKShareTypeText;
item.text = @"hi";
```

But now also want to apply it to Facebook. plz help me

i use above code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810146/is-it-possible-to-bypass-the-tweet-dialog-and-post-directly-to-twitter)

Thanks In Advance

Comment: use FBGraph to post directly to Facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's possible to imitate the Share dialog directly.

You can use the `/ID/feed` connection but the user status update will appear as "via your app".

Comment: ya but Id/Feed is used in graph Api and i want to use it in Sharekit

Answer (score 1):

FBGraph is much better way to use facebook API in your app.

download the FBGraph Api documents folder then add it to in your folder.
and read the instruction on facebook developer site http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/.

this is the sample code - [sample code](http://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API)

and let me know if you have any query about it.